# What’s the design pattern to store Lists of different objects in Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, interface, extends

Two basic patterns of object-oriented programming do not play well in object-relational mapping: extension and interfaces. If the business model requires to maintain lists whose members have different classes, what is the canonical approach to store them in a relational database?

I can think up various *work-arounds* to get this done somehow, starting from tables with *lots* of `null` columns, over index columns that require implicit uniqueness across several tables, up to storing serialized objects in String fields, but all of it seems unobvious and/or dangerously error-prone to me. I don’t want to vandalize a thoughtful object model either.

I wonder: What are the principal design patterns to follow if a good object design for the business model requires to maintain lists typed by an interface or superclass? Are there anti-patterns to beware of?